# How do I make a(n ascii) table to support my Excel question on superuser?

Tags: support, markdown, new-users, editing-help

I'd like to ask a question regarding Excel on the Stack Exchange Superuser site, and I have a sample set of data to help illustrate my request for help with a formula. It doesn't seem that HTML tables are supported, so I used an [ASCII table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to try and create something I could post as text. I have tried different formatting options but can't seem to get the columns lined up once it converts from mono spacing to the posting font. Here is an example of what my data looks like (with break tabs added, otherwise it would be even more of a jumbled mess). Can anyone please advise me how they format table data on these forums?  Do you use ASCII? Something else?

+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
| Contribution Type | % Contribution Match | % Salary |
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
| Type 1            |                  0.5 |        - |
| Type 1            |                  0.6 |        - |
| Type 1            |                      |        - |
| Type 2            |                    - |     0.03 |
| Type 2            |                    - |     0.04 |
| Type 2            |                    - |        0 |

*Update* thank you! This was marked a duplicate to a question on markdowns, which did help me to solve this by redirecting me to a related question about [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). The short answer is that yes, I can use ascii to post tables, so long as they are contained within a code block, which is created by putting four spaces at the beginning of each line. You can see the result of this below:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
| Contribution Type | % Contribution Match | % Salary |
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
| Type 1            |                  0.5 |        - |
| Type 1            |                  0.6 |        - |
| Type 1            |                      |        - |
| Type 2            |                    - |     0.03 |
| Type 2            |                    - |     0.04 |
| Type 2            |                    - |        0 |
```

Update #2: special thanks to Pierre for providing me with the [best answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange.com/posts/315202/timeline#comment_1033079) via the comments section. I do not see any icons to upvote, only flag, but I would like to give you credit for your help here. I hope I've done this properly. Thank you again.

Comment: Just insert 4 spaces in front of each line ... That is, you format it as predefined text (similar to what you do to show "code". Try it, you'll get it for sure ...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: May I say "***what else did you expect***"? Too bad there is no "convert comment to answer" facility on SE sites (so that you coud mark it as accepted ...). Though could "upvote" my prior comment if you'd want to. And/or you could further edit your quetion to "add credits" (with a link to my first comment, located at https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/315202/timeline#comment_1033079).